# How can I send information from one user to another using Firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app where users can exchange locations.

So far I've built a function that the user can use to send his location and any other user can see it. I'd like to modify my sendLocation() function so it sends the location to a specific user, and only that user would be able to see it, but I'm not sure what's the best way to do this.

This send the user location to the database

```
  sendLocation = () => {
    console.warn("sending location log", this.props);
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("/locations")
      .child(this.currentUser.uid)
      .child(Date.now())
      .set({
        uid: this.currentUser.uid,
        user: user,
        latitude: this.props.location.coords.latitude,
        longitude: this.props.location.coords.longitude,
        created_at: Date.now(),
        order: -Date.now()
      });
    this.sendPushNotification();
  };
```

Here is where I retrieve the locations

```
  readLocations = () => {
    allLocations = [];
    let locations = firebase
      .database()
      .ref("/locations")
      .child(this.currentUser.uid)
      .orderByChild("created_at")
      .startAt(last12hours);
    locations.on("value", snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(thing => {
        oneLocation = [];
        oneLocation.push(
          thing.val().uid,
          thing.val().latitude,
          thing.val().longitude,
          thing.val().user
        );
        allLocations.push(oneLocation);
      });
      this.setState({ locations: allLocations }, () => {
      });
    });
  };
```

I also have access to the users information. This function would be triggered BEFORE I send the location to the user.

```
  readFriends = () => {
    allFriends = [];
    let myFriends = firebase
      .database()
      .ref("/users")
      .orderByChild("first_name");
    myFriends.on("value", snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(thing => {
        oneFriend = [];
        oneFriend.push(thing.val().first_name, thing.val().last_name);
        allFriends.push(oneFriend);
      });
      this.setState({ friends: allFriends, modalVisible: true }, () => {
       });
       });
  };
```

Comment: What do you know about the user you're sending the message to?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I still need to figure out how to do it, but I would have his ID (I made an update with readFriends())

Answer (score 2):

To be able to detect whether somebody is writing their location to a friend, you'll first need to model friendships in the database. A very simple model for that is:

```
friends: {
  uid1: {
    uid2: true,
    uid3: true
  },
  uid2: {
    uid1: true
  }
}
```

So in the above data structure, `uid1` has marked `uid2` and `uid3` as their friends, while `uid2` has reciprocated and marked `uid1` as their friend. You'd typically secure the above so that a user can only write their own friends with:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "friends": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now with the above we can allow a user to write their location for people that have marked them as friends. We'll use another data structure for that, something like:

```
locations: {
  uid1: {
    uid2: "location of uid2"
  }
}
```

So in the above scenario, user `uid2` has written their location to `uid1/uid2` with something like:

```
firebase.database()
  .ref("/locations")
  .child("uid1") // the UID of someone who marked us as a friend
  .child(this.currentUser.uid)
  .set(...)
```

And you'd secure the above write operation with:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "locations": {
      "$friendid": {
        "$uid": {
          ".write": "auth.uid === $uid && 
                     root.child('friends').child($friendid).child(auth.uid).exists()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! But the thing is that there will be no friendships. Any user can send their location to another user, just like in Whatsapp, where any user can send a message to another.

Comment: In that case you'd only use the `locations` structure of my answer, and simplify the rules to now check for friendship.